# .NET isotropic image drawing

Tags: c#-3.0

Does anyone have an idea of how to resize an image isotropically? Meaning I give it a set width/height, and the image is scaled to fit at it's same proportions within that box, even if there is whitespace around it?

Comment: yes, i know how to do it :)... finding the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it:

```
    public Image ResizeIsotropic(Image src, Size sz)
    {
        double d1 = sz.Width / (double)sz.Height;
        double d2 = src.Width / (double)src.Height;

        if (d1 > d2)
        {
            src = ResizeByHeight(src, sz.Height);
        }
        else
        {
            src = ResizeByWidth(src, sz.Width);
        }

        Image rtn = null;
        using (Image thumbnail = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using (Graphics graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
            {
                graphic.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, sz.Width, sz.Height);
                graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphic.DrawImage(src, (sz.Width - src.Width)/2, (sz.Height - src.Height)/2, src.Width, src.Height);
                EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
                encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                ImageCodecInfo jpginfo = GetImageCodecInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, Quality);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                thumbnail.Save(ms, jpginfo, encoderParameters);
                rtn = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }

        theImage = rtn;
        return rtn;
    }


    private ImageCodecInfo GetImageCodecInfo(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        ImageCodecInfo jpginfo = null;
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo i in info)
        {
            if (i.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                jpginfo = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return jpginfo;
    }
```

the ResizeByWidth and ResizeByHeight functions are other parts of a library i have, they do exactly what you'd think they do.

here are the results:

[alt text http://imagebin.antiyes.com/images/0626614001263432575_87.jpg](http://imagebin.antiyes.com/images/0626614001263432575_87.jpg)

Comment: Any idea where I get GetImageCodecInfo?

Comment: yeah, i wrote that too, i'll post it.  the first image is the original, the second is the original resized to 300x300

Comment: Htrnm... so I just want to make Resize methods for the two in there?

Comment: You said they do exactly what they sound like - I'm not sure what you mean by that...

Comment: The ResizeByHeight resizes an image scaling it with the height set to what's passed in, the ResizeByWidth does the same but for the width.

basically it resizes it to fit in the area first, then draws it to that area offsetted by half the extra distance.

Comment: Erhm, that's kind of a key part of the whole process. That's part of what I can't seem to figure out how to do.

Comment: Even trying with that code gives errors that encoderParameters isn't valid.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it ... all of these extra parameters are causing a lot of trouble though. Is there anything that might explain how to use them?

Comment: scaling an image is a different question.  all the other code is so the image is resized nicely and not grainy.

Comment: Okay! I did some changes to your code and made it a bit simpler to understand. Thank you so much, your answer is immaculate, it really helped a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First calculate the size so that the width fits in the box. Then check if the calculated height is larger than the box, in that case you calculate the size so that the height fits in the box instead.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe John Boker's answer to be sufficient, this may be a more concise method of doing this:

```
static Bitmap ResizeIsotropic(Image img, Size newSize, Color backgroundColor)
{
  int Width, Height;

  if (img.Width >= img.Height)
  {
    Width = newSize.Width;
    Height = (int)(img.Height / (img.Width / Width));
  }
  else
  {
    Height = newSize.Height;
    Width = (int)(img.Width / (img.Height / Height));
  }

  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);

  using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
  {
    gfx.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gfx.Clear(backgroundColor);
    gfx.DrawImage(img, (bmp.Width / 2) - (Width / 2), (bmp.Height / 2) - (Height / 2), Width, Height);
  }

  return bmp;
}
```

Then, to call it simply do:

```
Bitmap bmp = ResizeIsotropic(Image.FromFile(@"c:\yourImage.jpg"), new Size(512, 512), Color.Black);
bmp.Save(@"c:\test.bmp");
```